# Getting unauthorized: authentication required in docker image deployment

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I have created an Azure Container registry and azure web app for containers and publish my code in it.
After that, I have created a CICD pipeline using Azure. Build and release pipelines are passed successfully. But on browsing the application, it is showing 'unauthorized: authentication required' error.

2020-07-14T12:24:42.737Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: api.azurecr.io/api
2020-07-14T12:24:43.270Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://api.azurecr.io/v2/api/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

Do I need to create a repository in the docker hub? What is the problem here?

Comment: have you tried to run `az acr login` ?

Comment: I have published my website in azure and running the web app for the container. Where to run this command?

Comment: In the machine  you try to pull the image from

Comment: Thanks, az acr login worked. But now it is giving Error response from daemon: Get https://apimanagement.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: Application not registered with AAD.Login failed.

Comment: You need to attach acr to this resource - this is how I manage to get this working from aks to car - `az aks update -n ${CLUSTER_NAME} -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME} --attach-acr ${ACR_NAME}
`

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/366